# Enable Button on RelayCommand WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Button is not getting enable on Command Enable, doEnable method. Click method is disabling button. 
Button IsEnabled is Bind with ViewModel public property IsEnable, which is setting true on doEnable.
Kindly advise what is wrong in below Code

**XAML:**

```
<Button Content="{Binding DataText}" Height="30" Width="80" Command="{Binding Enable}" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnable}" ></Button>
```

**Window2.cs:**

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ButtonEnableViewModel();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        if(sender is Button btn)
            btn.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

**ButtonEnableViewModel.cs**

```
class ButtonEnableViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public ButtonEnableViewModel() 
    {
        IsEnable = true;
        DataText = "Click Here";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChange(string name) 
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private RelayCommand _enableCmd;
    public RelayCommand Enable => _enableCmd ?? (_enableCmd = new RelayCommand(doEnable));

    public bool IsEnable { get; set; }
    public string DataText { get; set; }

    protected void doEnable(object obj) 
    {
        IsEnable = true;
        DataText = "Clicked";
        OnPropertyChange(nameof(IsEnable));
        OnPropertyChange(nameof(DataText));
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Kindly advise what is wrong in below Code"_ - it's a mess. Why do you mixing code-behind and view-model? Your `ButtonBase_OnClick` set `IsEnabled` property to `false`, but your `Enable` command set same property to `true`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to Enable the Button doEnable method. Its an executable example,

Comment: changing value of isEnabled property directly breaks binding

Comment: @tabby if it breaks Binding, how to fix it...

Comment: (this.DataContext as ButtonEnableViewModel).IsEnable = false; however whatever vasily.sib  said is true.

Comment: @tabby thanks, it works. Kindly post it as answer

Comment: @Akhter: You should use the `CanExecute` method of the command to disable the `Button`. Most implementations of the `ICommand` interface accepts a `Predicate<object>` that you can use to tell the command when to enable the command/button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally use the `CanExecute` method of the command to disable the `Button`. Most implementations of the `ICommand` interface accepts a `Predicate<object>` that you can use to tell the command when to enable the command/button.

In this case you might simply remove the event handler from the code-behind though and just handle the command in the view model:

```
<Button Content="{Binding DataText}" Height="30" Width="80" Command="{Binding Enable}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnable}" />
```

This should work since you set the `IsEnable` property in the `Execute` method of the command and raise the `PropertyChanged` event. You generally don't handle `Click` events in the code-behind of the view when you bind to a command of a view model.

If you use the `CanExecute` method of the command, you don't need to bind to the `IsEnable` property:

```
<Button Content="{Binding DataText}" Height="30" Width="80" Command="{Binding Enable}" />
```

**View Model:**

```
private RelayCommand _enableCmd;
public RelayCommand Enable => _enableCmd ?? (_enableCmd = new RelayCommand(doEnable, x => _isEnabled));

private bool _isEnabled;
public string DataText { get; set; }

protected void doEnable(object obj)
{
    _isEnabled = true;
    Enable.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    DataText = "Clicked";
    OnPropertyChange(nameof(DataText));
}
```